# Suggestions for how to retrieve primary keys for all rows with matching data (many columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server process where to save storage we need to store one row per unique record and reference the unique data set using the row's primary key.

Example scenario: given a SQL Server table similar to the following:

```
DataTable 
(
    DataID bigint, 
    name nvarchar(100), 
    birthday date, 
    value1 nvarchar(100), 
    value2 nvarchar(100)
)
```

Note: in reality there are ~30 columns

When new data is received we need to add the new data combinations to the DataTable and retrieve the DataIDs for all rows that were received, both new and existing.

One idea was to leverage EXCEPT and then perhaps INTERSECT, but I am unable to think of a way to get the IDs back from the rows identified.

The bigger picture for this need is that we have another table which is used to track all data received and we want to keep track of which unique data sets were received each day without having to store multiple copies of the data.

The data tracking table looks something like this:

```
ReceivedData (ID bigint, ReceivedDate datetime, DataID bigint)
```

The process currently in my head for this need could look something like this:

Given a new data in a table and the previously mentioned existing DataTable:

```
NewDataTable 
(
    name nvarchar(100), 
    birthday date, 
    value1 nvarchar(100), 
    value2 nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO DataTable (name, birthday, value1, value2)
    SELECT name, birthday, value1, value2 
    FROM NewDataTable
    EXCEPT
    SELECT name, birthday, value1, value2 
    FROM DataTable
```

We could probably use an OUTPUT clause here to get the DataIDs for the new records created, but we also need the DataIDs for records in the NewDataTable which match existing records in DataTable.

I know I could use join between the NewDataTable and the existing DataTable using all table columns, but this would be a heavy join and I'm hoping for a better way.

Thank you for all your time and ideas.

### Example Data Walkthrough

Existing [DataTable] records:

| DataID | name | birthday | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1/1/1990 | abc | 123 |
| 2 | Sally | 2/2/1990 | def | 321 |
| 3 | Steve | 3/3/1990 | ghi | 333 |

Existing [ReceivedData] records:

| ID | RecievedDate | DataID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 5/1/2023 03:01 | 1 |
| 101 | 5/1/2023 03:01 | 2 |
| 102 | 5/1/2023 03:01 | 3 |

Then, if new data is received on "5/2/2023 03:00" as follows:

New data received in [NewDataTable]

| name | birthday | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1/1/1990 | abc | 123 |
| Steve | 3/3/1990 | ghi | 333 |
| Alice | 4/3/1990 | aaa | 222 |

The desired data state after the process runs would be:

Resulting [DataTable] records:

| DataID | name | birthday | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1/1/1990 | abc | 123 |
| 2 | Sally | 2/2/1990 | def | 321 |
| 3 | Steve | 3/3/1990 | ghi | 333 |
| 4 | Alice | 4/3/1990 | aaa | 222 |

Resulting [ReceivedData] records:

| ID | RecievedDate | DataID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 5/1/2023 03:01 | 1 |
| 101 | 5/1/2023 03:01 | 2 |
| 102 | 5/1/2023 03:01 | 3 |
| 103 | 5/2/2023 03:00 | 1 |
| 104 | 5/2/2023 03:00 | 3 |
| 105 | 5/2/2023 03:00 | 4 |

Comment: if you use an insert and a update, you can have an output clause in both which would save both new and existing IDs for your latter logging usage

Comment: Since no data change is needed in the DataTable when the matching data record already exists I have not expected to do any updates. 
And if I'm understanding the idea you are suggesting, in order to do an update on the table only to retrieve the matching IDs, I would need to do a join on all fields to find the proper rows to update, so I might as well just do a select for the IDs based upon a join using all fields.

Comment: In case helpful I have added example data walkthrough in the original description.

Comment: Valnik kinda beat me to it, but will leave a comment anyway. The problem is that you will do a double dip, first to find which rows don't exist, and then do find the id of existing rows. I think it will work, but perhaps a MERGE will be more elegant here. So you do a dummy update, just to get the matching ID, which you can output into your log table together with the new inserted data. It might be worth testing if it's more performant than UPDATE, INSERT combo

Comment: Hi, siggemannen. Thanks for comment. I use MERGE and presume there is one join - more effective than combination Select existing-INSERT new. If someone, may be author,SGP , compares the methods on sufficiently large data, it will be very interesting. Updating of existing row - some is trick, justified by logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-- data model
create table DataTable(DataId int primary key identity,name nvarchar(100),birthday date
        ,value1 nvarchar(100),value2 nvarchar(100));
set identity_insert DataTable ON;
insert into DataTable (DataId,name,birthday,value1,value2) values 
 (1,'John','1990-01-01','abc','123')
,(2,'Sally','1990-03-03','def','321')
,(3,'Steve','1990-03-03','ghi','333')
;
set identity_insert DataTable OFF;

create table NewDataTable(name nvarchar(100),birthday date
        ,value1 nvarchar(100),value2 nvarchar(100));
insert into NewDataTable values 
 ('John','1990-01-01','abc','123')
,('Steve','1990-03-03','ghi','333')
,('Alice','1990-04-03','aaa','222')
;
create table LogTable(id int identity,actiondate datetime,action varchar(10),DataId int ,name nvarchar(100),birthday date
        ,value1 nvarchar(100),value2 nvarchar(100));

-- query
merge DataTable
using NewDataTable n on n.name=DataTable.name -- ... etc
when not matched then
  insert(name,birthday,value1,value2) values(n.name,n.birthday,n.value1,n.value2)
when matched then
   update set DataTable.name=n.name
output  
       getdate(),$action,inserted.*
into LogTable;

-- results
select * from DataTable;
select * From LogTable;
```

DataTable after query

| DataId | name | birthday | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1990-01-01 | abc | 123 |
| 2 | Sally | 1990-03-03 | def | 321 |
| 3 | Steve | 1990-03-03 | ghi | 333 |
| 4 | Alice | 1990-04-03 | aaa | 222 |

LogTable after query

| id | actiondate | action | DataId | name | birthday | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-17 20:17:13.520 | INSERT | 4 | Alice | 1990-04-03 | aaa | 222 |
| 2 | 2023-05-17 20:17:13.520 | UPDATE | 1 | John | 1990-01-01 | abc | 123 |
| 3 | 2023-05-17 20:17:13.520 | UPDATE | 3 | Steve | 1990-03-03 | ghi | 333 |

[Example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pl7IyRYR)

and with plan (https://dbfiddle.uk/yXVgKV92)

Comment: Thank you ValNik. I will try this. I did think Merge might help with this, but I admit I have little experience using it and haven't gotten back to trying to fit this in with it. 
The approach to do an update in order to get the record included in the output looks like a good approach. Thank you. I will give that a go!

Comment: Thanks again to both of you. I will try this out soon and see what I figure out. I admit I was hoping there my be a trick relating to how to get IDs when using INTERSECT or something because the performance for that has seemed better than joins. But I do think this will work. If I get some performance data I will post a followup. 
I had also considered trying to create a checksum or concatenated value for the data to help speed things up, but checksum of course can’t be trusted to be unique.